# Is $\text{Graph}(f)$ disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Is it possible to construct a function $f:D\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $D$ is disconnected but the $\text{Graph}(f)=\{(x,y): y=f(x)\}$ is connected?

My guess is that this can´t happen so I need to prove that $\text{Graph}(f)$ is disconnected but how can I give two open sets with the conditions of the definition of disconnected?

I would really appreciate any hints or suggestions

Comment: Assume $Graph(f)$ is connected and consider the projection $\pi_1:D\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow D$ on the first component. What do you know about its image?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible, and you could see it easily:

Take the projection: $ p:Graph(f)\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $p(x,f(x))=x$.

Then $p$ is continuous  (it's the projection), and it's image is $D$, which is not connected. But the image of a connected set by a continuous map is always connected, so $Graph(f)$ is not connected

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is not connected there two open, nonempty, disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $D\subset A\cup B$.

Let $A_f=A\times\Bbb R$, $B_f=B\times\Bbb R$. Now, $A_f$ and $B_f$ are open, nonempty disjoints sets in $\Bbb R^2$, $\text{Graph}(f)\subset A_f\cup B_f$ and $A_f\neq\emptyset\neq B_f$.

Comment: You should also note, that $\text{Graph}(f)$ has nonempty intersection with $A_f$ and $B_f$.

Comment: Yes, it is so obvious that I forgot it. Fixed.